# Weka: Multiclass classification for Text documents giving abnormal result

Tags: machine-learning, weka

I am new to Weka. I am trying to classify text documents after OCR process. The training corpus contains 286 mortgage documents and 57 note documents. The test dataset contains 1-100 text pages. So each line of the training and test dataset contains few paragraphs of text data. After classification text documents should be classified into mortgage or note properly.

I am doing a `StringToWordVector` operation combining both Training and Test dataset with missing values from Test dataset i.e. "?".

Steps are as follows:

1. Create training Arff file using following command line:

   > java -cp weka.jar weka.core.converters.TextDirectoryLoader -dir <text directory>

   This creates a training dataset with known classes i.e. mortgage, note
2. Create test Arff file with missing classes i.e "?"
3. Combine both training and test dataset
4. Run the classifier with following command line:

   > java -cp weka.jar weka.classifiers.meta.FilteredClassifier -t train.arff -test.arff -F "weka.filters.MultiFilter -F weka.filters.unsupervised.attribute.StringToWordVector -F weka.filters.unsupervised.attribute.Standardize" -d trained.model -p 0

I am running the above example from both Weka GUI and from command line as well. Everything works fine as far as commands are concerned. The results are abnormal. Not at all correct.

I have also tried to run `StringToWordVector` operation separately and tested through `NaiveBayes`, `NaiveBayesMultiNomial`, `J48` and other multiclass classifiers on the dataset but classification prediction is not correct. Always giving abnormal results.

Please help me to get the proper prediction result. Let me know if the above steps are correct and if I am doing anything wrong.

Comment: Could you provide the relevant parts of the output statistics, e.g. (in)correctly classified samples? Also, did you try classifying your training data with your model? That should give you a very high accuracy and could serve as further debugging info.